# How to place a VC in a navigation controller programmatically?

Tags: swift

I am currently getting an error whenever I try to present this VC. The error is *Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value* I believe it is because the VC is not in a navigation controller. How do I put this VC in a navigation controller(programmatically).

```
import UIKit
import AWSAuthCore
import AWSAuthUI
import AWSMobileClient

class SignInViewController: UIViewController {



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        AWSMobileClient.default()
        .showSignIn(navigationController: self.navigationController!, // this is where i get the error.
                         signInUIOptions: SignInUIOptions(
                               canCancel: true,
                               logoImage: UIImage(named: "MyCustomLogo"),
                                backgroundColor: UIColor.red)) { (result, err) in

        AWSMobileClient.default().initialize { (userState, error) in
                   if let userState = userState {
                       switch(userState){
                       case .signedIn:

                               DispatchQueue.main.async {


                           }
                       case .signedOut:
                           AWSMobileClient.default().showSignIn(navigationController: self.navigationController!, { (userState, error) in
                                   if(error == nil){       //Successful signin
                                       DispatchQueue.main.async {


                                       }
                                   }
                               })
                       default:
                           AWSMobileClient.default().signOut()

                       }

                   } else if let error = error {
                       print(error.localizedDescription)
                   }
               }

    }



    }




}
```

Here is the code from `AppDelegate`

```
import UIKit
import AWSAppSync
import AWSMobileClient


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var appSyncClient: AWSAppSyncClient?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let nav1 = UINavigationController()
        let mainView = SignInViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        nav1.viewControllers = [mainView]
        self.window!.rootViewController = nav1
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: TabBarController())
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        AWSMobileClient.default().addUserStateListener(self) { (userState, info) in
                      switch (userState) {
                      case .guest:
                          print("user is in guest mode.")
                      case .signedOut:
                        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(SignInViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
                          print("user signed out.")
                      case .signedIn:
                          print("user is signed in.")
                      case .signedOutUserPoolsTokenInvalid:
                          print("need to login again.")
                      case .signedOutFederatedTokensInvalid:
                          print("user logged in via federation, but currently needs new tokens")
                      default:
                          print("unsupported")
                      }
                  }


        AWSMobileClient.default().initialize { (userState, error) in
                 if let userState = userState {
                     print("UserState: \(userState.rawValue)")
                 } else if let error = error {
                     print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                 }
             }
        do {
            // You can choose the directory in which AppSync stores its persistent cache databases
            let cacheConfiguration = try AWSAppSyncCacheConfiguration()

            // AppSync configuration & client initialization
            let appSyncServiceConfig = try AWSAppSyncServiceConfig()
            let appSyncConfig = try AWSAppSyncClientConfiguration(appSyncServiceConfig: appSyncServiceConfig,
                                                                  cacheConfiguration: cacheConfiguration)
            appSyncClient = try AWSAppSyncClient(appSyncConfig: appSyncConfig)
            print("Initialized appsync client.")
        } catch {
            print("Error initializing appsync client. \(error)")
        }

        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embed the `SignInViewController` in a `UINavigationController`.

To do that, drag-and-drop a `UINavigationController` to the `Storyboard` and `CTRL + drag` from that `UINavigationController` to the `SignInViewController`, choose the relationship `rootViewController`

Programatically:

```
var nav1 = UINavigationController()
var mainView = SignInViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil) 
nav1.viewControllers = [mainView]
self.window!.rootViewController = nav1
```

Comment: are you initializing SignInViewController from AppDelegate?

Comment: Yes and it still threw the same error at `self.window!.rootViewController = nav1`

Comment: does the SignInViewController has StoryBoard? also could you post the Appdelegate?

Comment: I added it above

Comment: you have TabBarController as rootViewController assigned, that's the reason why it's not working. You can have only one rootViewController to a navController.

Comment: What should I change?

Comment: it's based on your need which controller one you need initially. If you need SignInController as Initial controller then remove this line,         window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: TabBarController())

Comment: I would like the `SignInController` to just be presented if the user is not signed in.  If they are signed in Would just like to show the `tabBarController`.